# ESI Cache - Login / Token is cached

Tags: symfony, caching, esi

I'm using Symfony 2.4 in my application with ESI Cache (validation cache). Now I have strange problem with login. For example when I log in to a user, log out and next try to log in to another account. Application gives me a token from a first user... It looks like some actions related with login are being cached ... I have no idea why is that and how to solve it...
I'm using FOS User Bundle.

Any ideas will be helpful, thanks in advance !